# HTML and NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsxmlparser, youtube-api

I use the youtube api to get descriptions from videos but sometimes not the full description shows up becuase of a `@amp;` how do I fix this?
BTW I use NSXMLParser.

Answer (score 0):

remove the @amp bye using `[yourString StringByReplacingOccurenceOfString:@"amp" withString:@""];`